# Bulk Update with ReactiveMongoTemplate

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb, reactive-mongo-java

In a reactive spring boot application, I have a list of items to update. I want to send a SINGLE command to my DB to apply the changes on different items. An equivalent to db.collection.updateMany if I may say. Is it possible? How?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,
ReactiveMongoTemplate has

```
updateMulti(Query query, UpdateDefinition update, Class<?> entityClass)
```

Updates all objects that are found in the collection for the entity class that matches the query document criteria with the provided updated document.

Comment: If I use the query to find the item 1 in the items list, I can update it with the UpdateDefinition I guess. What about the item 2? item 3 ... ? Do I need to write as many updateMulti as items to update? If so, I can just use the repository saveAll.
What I need, is to send a SINGLE mongodb command to update all the items.

Comment: YEah you can use saveAll()  or
 insert(Collection<? extends T> batchToSave, Class<?> entityClass)
Insert a Collection of objects into a collection in a single batch write to the database.
<T> reactor.core.publisher.Flux<T> insert(Collection<? extends T> batchToSave, String collectionName)
Insert a batch of objects into the specified collection in a single batch write to the database.

Comment: insert doesn't update.
saveAll does update but not in a SINGLE batch.
What I need is a way to update in a single batch.

Comment: @lori Yagami, did you get a solution for this ?