# Spring Webflux Reactive Mongo Bulk Operations (Java)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, reactive-mongo-java

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/2821

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1922?redirect=false

I have been looking for ReactiveBulk operations to update documents as a batch in Spring WebFlux.

Like in the Mongo Template

```
var bulkOps = mongoTemplate.bulkOps()
for(dto : List<DTO> DTOs) {
  Query query = new Query();
  query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(ID).is(dto.getId()));
  Update update = new Update()
                    .set(STATUS, dto.getStatus())
  bulkOps.updateOne(query, update)
}
bulkOps.execute();
```

is there a workaround to implement that operation in reactive way since reactivemongotemplate look like does not support that operation currently?

similiar topic in so: [Bulk Update with ReactiveMongoTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68905090/bulk-update-with-reactivemongotemplate)

Answer (score 2):

Quickly remind that Bulk is different than UpdateMulti.

Bulk is meant to write multiple objects in a single query, therefore, update various objects. On the other side, UpdateMulti is intended to update all lines where expression matches

As for  reactive bulk, you should be able to use `ReactiveMongoTemplate` and implement something like that:

```
reactiveMongoTemplate.getCollection("collection_name")
    .flatMap(mongoCollection -> {
            List<UpdateOneModel<Document>> operations = DTOs.stream()
                .map(dto -> {
                    Document doc = new Document("status", dto.getStatus());
                    
                    reactiveMongoTemplate.getConverter().write(dto, doc);
                    
                    Document filter = new Document("id", dto.getId());
                    
                    return new UpdateOneModel<Document>(filter, new Document("$set", doc))
                }).toList();
        
            return Mono.from(mongoCollection.bulkWrite(operations));
    });
```

You can also add custom options to `bulkWrite()` if you desire.

If more filter is needed, you can append them to the document

```
Document filter = new Document("id", dto.getId())
     .append("country", dto.getCountry);
```